# C++ - Clarifying when and how destructors are called

Tags: c++, dynamic, constructor, destructor, copy-constructor

So I have an entire program below that creates Book objects, initializes them, and prints any constructors/destructors that are created or destroyed throughout the execution of the program.

I have ran my code (and pasted the output below), and I am having trouble understanding how the destructors are being called. So I know that the constructors are destroyed in the opposite order in which they were created. But I don't get why four of the destructor statements have an id of 4. I'm assuming one came from the "explicit call to the copy constructor", the other came from "declaring and initializing book 6 from book 5", and the other came from the first part of "declaring and initializing books 1 to 4." But I'm confused as to where the extra id of 4 came from?

Additionally, I was wondering why a "-- dtor: 0" wasn't printed for the "declaring book 5" part where default ctor: 0 was created.

I would really appreciate any clarification!

main.cc:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#include "Book.h"


void func1(Book);
void func2(Book&);


int main()
{
  cout<<endl<<"Declaring and initializing books 1 to 4..."<<endl;

  Book b1(1, "Ender's Game", "Orson Scott Card");
  Book b2(2, "Dune", "Frank Herbert");
  Book b3(3, "Foundation", "Isaac Asimov");
  Book b4(4, "Hitch Hiker's Guide to the Galaxy", "Douglas Adams");

  cout<<endl<<"Declaring book 5..."<<endl;
  Book b5;
  b5.print();

  cout<<endl<<"Assigning book 4 to 5..."<<endl;
  b5 = b4;
  b5.print();

  cout<<endl<<"Declaring and initializing book 6 from book 5..."<<endl;
  Book b6 = b5;
  b6.print(); 

  cout<<endl<<"Calling func1()..."<<endl;
  func1(b1);

  cout<<endl<<"Calling func2()..."<<endl;
  func2(b2);

  cout<<endl<<"Explicit call to copy constructor..."<<endl;
  Book b7(b6);


  cout << endl << endl;

  return 0;
}

void func1(Book b)
{
  b.print();
}

void func2(Book& b)
{
  b.print();
}
```

book.cc:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#include "Book.h"

Book::Book(int i, string t, string a)
{
  cout<<"-- default ctor:  "<< i <<endl;
  id     = i;
  title  = t;
  author = a;
}

Book::Book(const Book& other)
{
  id     = other.id;
  title  = other.title;
  author = other.author;

  cout<<"-- copy ctor:  "<< id <<endl;
}


Book::~Book()
{
  cout<<"-- dtor:  "<< id <<endl;
}

void Book::print()
{
  cout<<"** "<< title <<" by "<<author<<endl;
}
```

book.h:

```
#ifndef BOOK_H
#define BOOK_H

#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Book
{
  public:
    Book(int=0, string="Unknown", string="Unknown");
    Book(const Book&);
    ~Book();
    void print();

  private:
    int id;
    string title;
    string author;
};

#endif
```

OUTPUT:

```
Declaring and initializing books 1 to 4...
-- default ctor:  1
-- default ctor:  2
-- default ctor:  3
-- default ctor:  4

Declaring book 5...
-- default ctor:  0
** Unknown by Unknown

Assigning book 4 to 5...
** Hitch Hiker's Guide to the Galaxy by Douglas Adams

Declaring and initializing book 6 from book 5...
-- copy ctor:  4
** Hitch Hiker's Guide to the Galaxy by Douglas Adams

Calling func1()...
-- copy ctor:  1
** Ender's Game by Orson Scott Card
-- dtor:  1

Calling func2()...
** Dune by Frank Herbert

Explicit call to copy constructor...
-- copy ctor:  4


-- dtor:  4
-- dtor:  4
-- dtor:  4
-- dtor:  4
-- dtor:  3
-- dtor:  2
-- dtor:  1
```

Comment: The statement `b5 = b4` causes `b5.id` to have a value of `4` (like `b4.id` does).  That's how the compiler-generated assignment operator works - it doesn't call a constructor.   In the output, the second last `-- dtor: 4` corresponds to destruction of `b5`.

Comment: Why do you think `b5` would have an `id` of 0, but `b6` and `b7` - which you copied from `b5` - would have an `id` of 4?

Comment: You might want to print the address of `this` within ctor's/dtor in order to see when a new object instance is instantiated and when it gets destroyed. Your way its confusing because you got four different objects with `id == 4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I don't get why four of the destructor statements have an id of 4

because you assign `b4` to `b5` in statement

`b5 = b4;`

then copy construct `b6 = b5;` and `b7(b6);` each of them having `id` = 4, so destructor prints

`-- dtor:  4`

> Additionally, I was wondering why a "-- dtor: 0" wasn't printed for the "declaring book 5" part where default ctor: 0 was created.

because when `Book b5;` is created it had `id` = 0 but when code assigned `b4` to `b5` `id` became 4, hence no "-- dtor: 0" was printed.